# UIWebView displaying raw html tags

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiwebview

I am working on an iPad app (iOS 5 ARC) that will show threads data from server using php based webservices.

After getting JSON dictionary data from server, I am using `UIWebView` to show data but it is showing raw HTML tags.

Please suggest how to fix it.

Code I'm using:

```
[cell.webVwPostedContent loadHTMLString:[dic objectForKey:kpost_shortDesc] baseURL:nil];
```

Below is an html data string I am getting from server and showing in web view:

```
<u><em><strong>http:\/\/www.msn.com\/<\/strong><\/em><\/u><br \/>\r\n
By clicking &quot;OK&quot;, you agree to the Microsoft Service Agreement 
and Privacy Statement. You&#39;ll get future updates to Bing Bar and other 
Microsoft products from Microsoft Update. This software may also download 
and install some updates automatically.
```

Comment: can you log the `[dic objectForKey:kpost_shortDesc]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with your string i.e.

```
<u><em><strong>http:\/\/www.msn.com\/<\/strong><\/em><\/u><br \/>
```

It should be like this

```
<u><em><strong>http://www.msn.com/</strong></em></u><br/>
```

The character `\/` is not any escape sequence. For `/` you don't need any escape sequence. Just put `/` in your response string.
I suggest to change the response generated by your server.

---

I tried

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<u><em><strong>http:\/\/www.msn.com\/<\/strong><\/em><\/u><br \/>\r\n\
     By clicking &quot;OK&quot;, you agree to the Microsoft Service Agreement \
     and Privacy Statement. You&#39;ll get future updates to Bing Bar and other \
     Microsoft products from Microsoft Update. This software may also download \
     and install some updates automatically." baseURL:nil];
```

it works for me

Comment: Thanks, Inder to show your help.. But I check and found that in webview the output is similar to the string that you suggest above: <u><em><strong>http://www.msn.com/</strong></em></u><br/>

Comment: Could you do 2 things first put log of `[dic objectForKey:kpost_shortDesc]` and screenshot of your webview

Comment: Log of the html string: &lt;u&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;http://www.msn.com/&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
By clicking &amp;quot;OK&amp;quot;, you agree to the Microsoft Service Agreement and Privacy Statement. You&amp;#39;ll get future updates to Bing Bar and other Microsoft products from Microsoft Update. This software may also download and install some updates automatically.

Comment: I dont know how to upload screenshot of the ipad on this site.

Comment: Yeah you need some reputation for that..but there are other image uploading sites also..try that till then let me check you string

Comment: If I tried the hard code string as you have tried then it works...[webView loadHTMLString:@"<u><em><strong>http:\/\/www.msn.com\/<\/strong><\/em><\/u><br \/>\r\n\
     By clicking &quot;OK&quot;, you agree to the Microsoft Service Agreement \
     and Privacy Statement. You&#39;ll get future updates to Bing Bar and other \
     Microsoft products from Microsoft Update. This software may also download \
     and install some updates automatically." baseURL:nil]; But in case of runtime string from server it failed

Comment: it because your server is sending wrong string. It is sending the Html tag values for `<` as `&lt`. Your log `[dic objectForKey:kpost_shortDesc]` should print `<u><em><strong>http://www.msn.com/</strong></em></u><br/>\r\n
By clicking &quot;OK&quot;, you agree to the Microsoft Service Agreement 
and Privacy Statement. You&#39;ll get future updates to Bing Bar and other 
Microsoft products from Microsoft Update. This software may also download 
and install some updates automatically.
` then only it will work